# How to make an image logo responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm changing my WordPress theme to [Balance theme](http://demo.studiopress.com/balance/) and I try to make the image logo responsive and center when viewed in tablet & smartphone.

[This is my site](http://www.prospekdigital.com/).

I'm using [JetPack Custom CSS](http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/) to change the default text Site Title to image (logo). Here is my custom CSS:

```
#title-area {
    background: url(http://www.prospekdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/logo-pd-350-135.png) no-repeat;
    height: 135px;
    width: 350px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

The image logo display correctly in desktop view but not center when I resize my browser (to test tablet & smartphone media queries).

I've tried `text-align:center;` and `margin:0 auto;` but still didn't work.

Desktop (OK)

[image]

When I resize my browser... (NOT OK)

[image]

...and this

[image]

How to make the logo responsive and center when I resize my browser?

Comment: For me its working fine in firefox.. In which browser you are checking?

Comment: @Etash please check my site: http://www.prospekdigital.com/

Comment: use `max-width:350px` and `margin:0px auto` for`#title-area`

Answer (score 0):

try the following css:

```
 image  { margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; 
    background: url(http://www.prospekdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/logo-pd-350-135.png) no-repeat;
        height: 135px;
        width: 350px;
        text-indent: -9999px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks @user10!

```
#title-area {
    max-width: 350px;
    background: url(http://www.prospekdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/logo-pd-350-135.png) no-repeat;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using media query like this:

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    #title-area {
    background: url("http://www.prospekdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/logo-pd-350-135.png") no-repeat center top;
    height: 135px;
    width: 350px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the `max-width` to `100%`. So when the windows is smaller than the width of the logo, it will resize.

Then set the `width` to the size you want the logo to be.
And use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.

```
@media (max-width:767px){
   .logo {
      display: block;
      width: 180px;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpno3co3/1/